# Is there a way to order applications in the launcher by frequency of use?

Tags: launcher

Is there a way to order buttons in launcher by frequency of use? Have around 40 items and small screen size to view all of them. Did a search on software center, search engines but nothing about it.

Comment: What do you mean by launcher? You mean the bar on the left?

Than all you need to do is to drag and drop.

Comment: Yes, the bar on the left (don't know official/technical name). Sometimes I use some programs more than other and I'm tired of dragging and dropping with touch pad. Please don't tell me 'buy a mouse/larger screen' as an answer :)

Answer (score 5):

For your case, since you have a small screen and a lot of items to put in the launcher, I would first suggest the following:

1. Categorize Items
   By using a tool like **[Drawers](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/12/unity-stacks-application-drawers-gets.html)** you can save a lot of space if you group apps with similar usage (Drawing apps, sound apps, office apps...)

   To install, copy/paste the following lines in the terminal:

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ian-berke/ppa-drawers`
   `sudo apt-get update`
   `sudo apt-get install drawers`

   To use is easy, create a "Drawer", put it in the launcher and just drag from the Dash the items you wish to have in that specific drawer.

   [image]
2. Manually put in the top, the most used apps. Even though is manual, at least it will save you more time since you have the most used ones in the top.
3. Dash remembers. Open Dash an by typing the first letters of an app you normally use or rarely use it will pop in. You don't even have to write the whole name. If it appears as the first one, just press Enter. I know is not a solution but since what you are looking is to save you some time, pressing the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> and typing 3 or 4 letters is faster than looking for the app in the Launcher sometimes.

   [image]
4. Post the idea in http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/ so it gets picked up and maybe included in a future version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Drawers is close to what I need but didn't went well for me, could help while that kind of feature is developed.

I [posted the idea](http://brainstorm.ubuntu.com/idea/30416/) into the brainstorm, thanks for the suggestions.